# lcd.print then dataFile.print

Tags: programming

My program is a bit large and I'm worried about stability.

I need to print data to both a file and to my LCD. It's like this:

```
if (hour<10) {
    dataFile.print("0");
}
dataFile.print(hour, DEC);
dataFile.print(":");
if (minute<10) {
    dataFile.print("0");
}
dataFile.print(minute, DEC);
dataFile.print(":");
if (second<10) {
    dataFile.print("0");
}
```

Then

```
if (hour<10) {
    lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(hour, DEC);
lcd.print(":");
if (minute<10) {
    lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(minute, DEC);
lcd.print(":");
if (second<10) {
    lcd.print("0");
}
```

What is a smart way to make this shorter? Should I write a function to add the leading zero then another that does something like:

```
void printboth (thing) {
    dataFile.print(thing);
    lcd.print(thing);
}
```

good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What will use less memory, an array or if ... else?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/what-will-use-less-memory-an-array-or-if-else)

Comment: You asked an almost identical question here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13876/what-will-use-less-memory-an-array-or-if-else where you start: `I'm trying to make my sketch smaller.`  Please stick to one question for one topic to avoid splitting answers.

Comment: Give `__attribute__((always_inline)) void printboth (thing)` a try and see if it results in a smaller size. PS make sure you are using the latest version of the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You could format the data with snprintf:

```
char timestamp[9];
snprintf(timestamp, 9, "%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second);
dataFile.print(timestamp);
lcd.print(timestamp);
```

`%02d` in the snprintf *format* means "print at least 2 digits of this value and pad with leading zeros".

Comment: While true, note that `*printf()` will increase code size a lot.

Comment: Define "a lot".  I make it an increase of 1046 bytes and the program is far more readable.

Comment: I'm making changes with the main goal of making the sketch smaller